# PowerShell SecureBoot detection script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to determine wether SecureBoot is enabled or not using PowerShell.
As of now the value is set to Enabled, however my detection script always displays Disabled.
I might be doing it wrong but I'm close I think so please have a look at my script and let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
#Install module Get-BIOS if not already installed
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name GetBIOS) {
    Write-Host "Module exists"
} 
else {
    Install-Module -Name GetBIOS -Repository PSGallery -Force
}

#Set variable $SecureBoot
[String]$SecureBoot = (Get-Bios | Select-Object -Property Setting,Value | Where-Object {$_.Setting -eq "SecureBoot"})

try {
    if ($SecureBoot -eq "Enabled") {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Enabled"; exit 1
    } else {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Disabled"; exit 0
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output "Issues occured while attempting to detect $SecureBoot : $($_.Exception.Message)"; exit 1
}
```

Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: Your variable `$SecureBoot` is not a string, but because you specify two properties in the Select-Object, this is an **object** with two properties. Remove the cast to `[string]` and try `if ($SecureBoot.Value -eq "Enabled")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment:

With `Select-Object -Property Setting,Value` you are retrieving an **object** with these two properties, not a string, so either

Remove the cast to `[string]` and use the `.Value` property in the test:

```
$SecureBoot = (Get-Bios | Select-Object -Property Setting,Value | Where-Object {$_.Setting -eq "SecureBoot"})

try {
    if ($SecureBoot.Value -eq "Enabled") {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Enabled"; exit 1
    } else {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Disabled"; exit 0
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output "Issues occured while attempting to detect SecureBoot : $($_.Exception.Message)"; exit 1
}
```

OR

capture only the `.Value` property in $SecureBoot

```
$SecureBoot = (Get-Bios | Select-Object -Property Setting,Value | Where-Object {$_.Setting -eq "SecureBoot"}).Value

try {
    if ($SecureBoot -eq "Enabled") {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Enabled"; exit 1
    } else {
        Write-Output "Secure Boot is Disabled"; exit 0
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output "Issues occured while attempting to detect SecureBoot : $($_.Exception.Message)"; exit 1
}
```